# Inject dependency for type instanciated inside a loop

Tags: java, dependency-injection

I would like to use dependency injection for `Implementation` in this situation:

```
public interface Implementable{[...]}
public class Implementation implements Implementable{[...]}

public class DummyClass()
{
    private List<Implementable> testList;
    public DummyClass()
    {
        testList = new ArrayList<Implementable>();
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Implementable testVar = new Implementation(i);
            testList.add(testVar);
        }
    }
}
```

As much as I managed to gather, this isn't possible. Neither by injection through the constructor nor by using generics. Also, I would much prefer a native solution that doesn't rely on an external library to achieve this.

---

**Edit:**
Any solution would require that `DummyClass` would not have to know about which implementation of `InterfaceType` is to be instantiated inside the loop.

I was thinking about using generics, but that failed as `InterfaceType testVar = new T(i);` is not allowed. Also, the `newInstance()` method wasn't feasible because of the constructor requiring arguments. While this still was possible, it required too much reflection (`getConstructor`) and loss of type safety for my taste of a clean approach.

I'm perfectly satisfied to hear that what I'm trying to achieve can't be accomplished in any recommendable way. This question is in the hope that I did miss something though.

---

**Edit2:**
I was trying to go with a similar solution to the one provided by drewmoore but came across a flaw that I hadn't thought about.

Interfaces don't declare any requirements for the constructor. With this method I would have to use the same constructor in all implementations of the interface.

This made me think about the builder pattern. Which still arrives at the same caveat as the interface would need to define the building methods and thus again would have to make requirements for how all implementations have to be built.

Is there any other way for delayed construction? That is, a means that would enable me to inject an instance of the implementation I would like to use (`public DummyClass(InterfaceType implementation)`) but only construct (or build or initialise) it inside the loop where it then would return copies of itself.

But then again. I increasingly feel that what I'm trying to achieve won't be possible. Or that it shouldn't be done because of unjustified additional complexity or imposed restrictions. I might then rather accept the direct dependency of this class on the implementation and thank drewmoore for her insights.

Comment: The question is not clear to me. Could you add more details about what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I would like `DummyClass` not to depend on `Implementation`. Only on the interface `InterfaceType`. The only way I can see to possibly achieve that appears to be injection. Only in my case I can't simply inject an instance and use it because the loop creates different instances depending on the loop counter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After giving this further thought and inspired by the now unfortunately deleted answer of drewmoore I came to the following conclusion:

While I felt uneasy about using an interface to declare a contract on construction, as stated in my second edit, I now realised that this was exactly what the situation required. I meant to be able to construct this object in a certain way inside the loop. Therefore the requirements needed by this loop had to be formulated. Naturally an interface is ideal for this job.

Taking the initial example, my solution looks like this:

```
DummyClass dummyInstance = new DummyClass(new ImplementationProvider());

///////

public interface Implementable{[...]}
public class Implementation implements Implementable{[...]}

public interface ImplementationProviderAware
{
    public Implementable createImplementation(Integer counter);
}

public class ImplementationProvider implements ImplementationProviderAware
{
    public Implementable createImplementation(Integer counter)
    {
        return new Implementation(counter);
    }
}

public class DummyClass(ImplementationProviderAware implementationProvider)
{
    private List<Implementable> testList;
    public DummyClass()
    {
        testList = new ArrayList<Implementable>();
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Implementable testVar = implementationProvider.createImplementation(i);
            testList.add(testVar);
        }
    }
}
```